# How are digital signatures useful?

Tags: digital-signature, public-key-encryption

As per my understanding, if A and B want to talk and X is the man in the middle,  then X can just delete B's public key and make A believe that X's public key is actually B's public key. Now whenever A asks for a digital signature from B, the message will actually go to X. X will use his private key to sign the digest, which then A will decrypt using X's public key, thinking that it was B who signed it.

This is a typical man in the middle attack scenario, and there does not seem a clear solution as to how Digital Signatures can be helpful in this case.

My question:1) Is there some way that A and B can communicate even if they have X in the middle.
2) If not, then why are digital signatures useful(under what assumptions). An assumption can be as simple as:: X can only look at the public keys but not modify them(X cannot turn B's public key to X's public key).

Comment: Is this right place to ask this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say A is Alice and B is her Bank. The bank gets a public key certificate signed by a trusted authority whose key Alice already knows. The certificate proves that a certain public key actually belongs to that bank. When Alice tries to connect to her bank, if Xavier tries to switch the bank's key for his own, Alice won't trust Xavier's key, because it isn't certified as belonging to the bank. If Xavier tries to replace Alice, he won't be able to log in as Alice. He doesn't have her password, and he can't get it, because he can't successfully pose as her bank.

Comment: So the assumption can be this that there is a trusted Certificate Authority in between, which has already communicated with different parties and noted down their public keys. While it was doing so , there was no Man in the Middle. Am I correct?

Comment: @DipanshuVerma: Pretty much. While in theory, the CA could do all sorts of stuff to authenticate people when they get certificates that would be impractical to do for every communication, in practice, the requirements to get a certificate are surprisingly weak.

Comment: Last question, probably you can help:

if B takes the services of CA, it will encrypt the public key of B with its own private key. So whenever B signs a message and sends to A, A needs to decrypt it using B's public key. B's public key will be with the CA. The CA will issue A its own Pubic Key (CA-Public), and B's public key encrypted by CA-private .

Why all this? If there is a man in the middle, he can always pose as CA first, and provide A with his own public key. Where does this chain end?

Comment: Reposting:

if B takes the services of CA, it will encrypt the public key of B with its own private key. So whenever B signs a message and sends to A, A needs to decrypt it using B's public key. B's public key will be with the CA. The CA will issue A its own Pubic Key (CA-Public), and B's public key encrypted by CA-private .

Why all this? If there is a man in the middle, he can always pose as CA first, and provide A with his own public key. Where does this chain end?   Can CA Public keys not be tampered with? Why(because they are already hardcoded in browsers?)

Comment: @DipanshuVerma: If they MITM all your senses and trap you in the matrix, you're screwed. The assumption is that there are channels they can't MITM; for example, root certificates come pre-installed in your computer, and if you really want to, you can confirm them against other people's root certificates, in person if need be. Also, your description of the process isn't quite right; for example, the CA does not need to communicate with Alice after Alice has its root certificate.